# Interactive backup tool

Tags: backup, diff

I am looking for a backup (or diff) tool where I can select *interactively* which file I want to copy towards my external hard-disk.

Let me explain with further details: I have two computers and an external hard disk. All the disks have (somewhere) the same directory structure and, at some point, the same content.

I can modify files/directory structures in any of the two computers. Modify means:
  - create/delete (on purpose or not)/move new files and dir,
  - improve or *alter* some files.

So I'm looking for a tool working like `diff`, which shows the differences between two directory trees and *ask* me what to do (ie, in which direction to copy/remove).

`meld` appeared to do it, but its not really efficient with my configuration (~30GB over data), do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Have a look at unison.

Comment: What about rsync?

Comment: Isn't it a shopping question?

Comment: @jordanm rsync is not interactive, as far as I could see, it's only one way

Comment: @DeerHunter what's a shopping question ??

Comment: @Marco I'm trying it, looks promising

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/ :) Mind, as long as our recommendations are confined to concise comments, you are **mostly** safe. Yet, it may be advisable to sharpen your question a bit...

Answer (score 2):

You may try out [Synkron](http://synkron.sourceforge.net/). It's a cross-platform application. However, it's more of a Synchronization tool.

You may "Analyse" the files that have changed, the files which doesn't exist in the other directory and all the differences between the two/multiple sets of folders. You may also filter to only show the files which are affected.

[image: synkron]